# Convolution yields matrix?

Tags: real-analysis

The following screenshot is taken from an article dealing with cellular automata.,

[image]

When reading this passage, I am wondering in which sense one may get $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1\\1 & 1 & 1\\1 & 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}$ as the convolution of 
$$
\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}\text{ and }\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 &1\end{pmatrix}.
$$

*I am not quite sure if I got it right, but here is how I do understand it.*

**Edit**

It seems to me that this refers to some kind of discrete dynamics on a grid, where the matrix $\text{square}(1)$ tells us which weights the neighbor cells get and as a neighborhood $N(i,j)$ of a cell on position $(i,j)$ we are considering 
$$
N(i,j)=\left\{(i-1,j-1),(i-1,j),(i-1,j+1),(i,j),(i,j-1),(i,j+1),(i+1,j-1),(i+1,j),(i+1,j+1)\right\}.
$$

By $u_{i,j}^k$ denote the value of the cell on grid position $(i,j)$. Then, as far as I see, we first consider only the left and the right neighborcells on position $(i-1,j)$ and $(i+1,j)$, respectively and get the first iteration by
$$
u_{i,j}^{k+1}=u_{i-1,j}^k+u_{i+1,j}^k
$$
Then, for the second iteration, one seems to need the sum of  $u_{i,j+1}^{k+1}$ and $u_{i,j-1}^{k+1}$. To compute these both summands, we need $u_{i-1,j+1}^k, u_{i+1,j+1}^k$ as well as $u_{i-1,j-1}^k$ and $u_{i+1,j-1}^k$. All together one should get

$$
u_{i,j}^{k+2}=u_{i,j}^{k+1}+u_{i,j+1}^{k+1}+u_{i,j-1}^{k+1}=u_{i-1,j}^k+u_{i+1,j}^k+u_{i-1,j+1}^k+u_{i+1,j+1}^k+u_{i-1,j-1}^k+u_{i+1,j-1}^k.
$$

Another way to describe these two iterations should be something like
$$
(a\star (a^T\star u^k)_{i,j})_{i,j}=((a\star a^T)\star u^k)_{i,j}
$$
where $a=\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}$

or, describing both steps together,

$$
(\text{square}(1)\star u^k)_{i,j}.
$$

Anyway, both expressions should be the same, i.e. 
$$
((a\star a^T)\star u^k)_{i,j}=(\text{square}(1)\star u^k)_{i,j}.
$$

I guess this is meant by saying that $\text{square}(1)$ is constructed as the convolution of $a$ and $a^T$.

Am I right?

Comment: Matrix product?

Comment: dont know what you mean. is matrix product the same as convolution?!

Comment: If you matrix-multiply the two matrices in your last line then you get the matrix in your first line.

Comment: What do you mean by "convolution"?

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Improved my question.